# How to concatenate CSS files with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I want to concat css files like I do with my JS files and I seem to miss something regarding the process.

My code and its results:

Consts/dependencies:

```
const config = require('./src/config');
const isProduction = config.isProduction;
const gulp = require('gulp')
    , concat = require('gulp-concat')
    , minify = require('gulp-minify')
    , uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
    , concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css')
    , buffer = require('gulp-buffer')
    , rename = require('gulp-rename')
    , request = require('request')
    , source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
    , merge = require('merge2')
const index_dest = './public_html/';
const main_app_script = './dist/main.min.js';
const header_styles = './dist/head_styles.min.css';
```

when I try this it works for JS files:

```
gulp.task('merge_scripts', () => {
    if (isProduction) {
        const libraries = gulp.src([...underscore, ...angular, ...indexPageFiles]).pipe(concat('app_user_controllers.js', {newLine: '\r\n'}));
        const loki = request('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lokijs/1.3.16/lokijs.min.js').pipe(source('./public_html/dist/loki.js'));
        const app_user_controllers = gulp.src([...misc, ...appConfigFiles]).pipe(concat('libraries.js', {newLine: '\r\n'}));
        return merge(libraries, loki, app_user_controllers)
            .pipe(buffer())
            .pipe(concat('temp', {newLine: '\r\n'}))
            .pipe(minify())
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(rename(main_app_script))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(index_dest));
    }
});
```

result: I get a correct main.min.js that contains all JS I need.

When I try to do something similar for CSS files it doesn't work:

```
gulp.task('merge_head_styles', () => {
    if (isProduction) {
        const head_before_fonts = gulp.src(basic.map(css => { return css.path })).pipe(source('temp1.css'));
        const fonts = request('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro').pipe(source('temp2.css'));
        const head_after_fonts = gulp.src([...beyond, ...custom].map(css => { return css.path })).pipe(source('temp3.css'));
        return merge(head_before_fonts, fonts, head_after_fonts)
            .pipe(buffer())
            .pipe(concatCss('temp_head_styles'))
            .pipe(rename(header_styles))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(index_dest));
    }
});
```

result: I get a head_styles.min.css file that contains only a part from the css in the fonts link:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Source Sans Pro'), local('SourceSansPro-Regular'), url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v9/ODelI1aHBYDBqgeIAH2zlNzbP97U9sKh0jjxbPbfOKg.ttf") format('truetype');
}
```

instead of all css concatenated.

right now i don't want to minify/uglify my css files, only to concat them to a single file.

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

[`vinyl-source-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream) is used to generate a [`vinyl` file](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl) stream from a regular character stream.

For example `request()` returns a character stream so you need `source()` to turn it into a `vinyl` stream.

However `gulp.src()` already returns a stream of `vinyl` files, so `source()` is useless here. You probably want to use `concat()` instead (as you do in your `merge_scripts` task).

So these two lines:

```
 const head_before_fonts = gulp.src(basic.map(css => { return css.path })).pipe(source('temp1.css'));
 const head_after_fonts = gulp.src([...beyond, ...custom].map(css => { return css.path })).pipe(source('temp3.css'));
```

Should be this instead:

```
 const head_before_fonts = gulp.src(basic.map(css => { return css.path })).pipe(concat('temp1.css'));
 const head_after_fonts = gulp.src([...beyond, ...custom].map(css => { return css.path })).pipe(concat('temp3.css'));
```

Not sure how you were able to get any output at all though, since `vinyl-source-stream` throws an exception if the input isn't a character stream.

Comment: thanks, I've made that change and I still get the result. What else should I look for in my code?

Comment: Dunno. If you want help, you'll have to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Minimal – It's as minimal as I could, I don't have much code besides it.
Complete – What other info/code do I need to provide to make it complete?

Comment: Create a new folder. To that folder add ONLY the stuff you have in your question, nothing else. Can you execute the code and reproduce the problem? If not your question is still missing stuff.